# CHALLENGE: Non-volatile formula to dynamically reference any cell in any sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

**How do you dynamically reference any cell based on a variable sheetname or number and row & column number selection (say via a dropdown list)?**

I know INDIRECT would be the standard approach (detailed below), but because INDIRECT is volatile (recalculates for each and every minor workbook change) it can slow down your spreadsheet considerably. Can this be done using non-volatile means? I also know 3D references can be useful in select cases where you are e.g. summing or averaging across multiple sheets, but it won't work for individual cell addressing.

I will also propose my own answers to this question using INDEX(CHOOSE(...)), but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: I like this style of Q&A, will have a bash with my own answer later today if i get some free time

Comment: Refer to this link: https://www.contextures.com/xlfunctions05.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, the easy/usual/volatile way to dynamically address any cell in any sheet**

Lets say the required sheetname is in A1 ="JAN" and row and column numbers are in B1 =1 and C1 =1, then:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(B1, C1,,,A1))
```

would return the reference/value in JAN!$A$1. You can also return a whole range like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(B1, C1,,,A1)&":"&ADDRESS(9,C1)))
```

Which would return the value of SUM(JAN!$A$1:$A$9)

**Now, for a non-volatile method**

You can use the following non-volatile formula to index into any cell in any sheet, given that the list of sheets are static/or can be updated manually as needed. The CHOOSE function can return a reference to each sheet in the workbook based on index number supplied to CHOOSE. You have to use CHOOSE with INDEX as INDEX does not work normally across multiple sheets.

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE(*sheetnumber*,Sheet1!$A:$ZFD,Sheet2!$A:$ZFD,Sheet3!$A:$ZFD),*row number*,*column number*).
```

You must extend this formula manually to include every sheet in your workbook. The order that you place them in the CHOOSE function list determines the CHOOSE index *sheetnumber* order (not the order in which the sheets are sorted in the workbook).

If would be preferable to define the lengthy INDEX(CHOOSE(...)) function as a named cell or range, so that you don't have to type it out in several cell formulae (and if you have to edit it/add a new sheet, you only have to edit the defined name once). You can use relative define names to add the variables for sheet, row and column numbers to the named range in adjacent cells, or in Office 365 define the name say SHEETINDEX using the lambda function `=LAMBDA(sheetnum, r, c, INDEX(CHOOSE(sheetnum,Sheet1!$A:$ZFD,Sheet2!$A:$ZFD,Sheet3!$A:$ZFD),r,c)`. This way you can use the named range like a function `=SHEETINDEX(1,1,1)` to return Sheet1!$A$1.